# Spectrum of compact operator between different Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Let $X, Y$ be two different Banach spaces, and let $T: X \to Y$ be a compact linear operator. Suppose the identity $I : X \to Y$ **is well-defined**. (For example, we could have $X = L^2([0,1])$ and $Y = L^1([0,1])$, both equipped with the Lebesgue measure).

Do most/all elementary results in spectral theory hold in that setting? For example, is it true that the spectrum of $T$ is discrete and that the eigenvalues of $T$ only accumulate at $0$? Is there a simple way to see that without reproving the result? Practically all textbooks only deal with the case where $X = Y$...

Comment: As formulated the problem is ill posed. You're probably thinking of spectra of *unbounded* operators.

Comment: I may be just repeating @LiviuNicolaescu's statement, but what is the spectrum in this case?  I guess that you mean that $T - \lambda I$ is not invertible—but not one-sided, or not two-sided invertible?  If the latter, then it seems that most operators will have spectrum equal to most of $\mathbb C$.  If the former, then which side?

Comment: so we are considering $T = Id_{XY}T_{XX}$ where $T_{XX}$ is a compact operator $X\to X$, and $Id_{XY}$ is ... what do we know on $Id_{XY}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "$I$ is well-defined", I presume you mean you have a continuous injection $\iota$ of $X$ into $Y$.  If $X$ and $Y$ are not isomorphic it will not be a bijection, because there is no continuous linear bijection from $X$ to $Y$,   and the same applies to $T - \lambda \iota$.  Thus $T - \lambda \iota$ will never be invertible, and the "spectrum" of $T$ will be all of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I see... That answers my question. Thanks a lot!